# Problem with probsoln package

Tags: probsoln

I use probsoln package to typeset exercise book.
Here's my code.

```
\documentclass[
headings=big,
chapterprefix=true,% like in standard class "report",
fontsize=10,
a5paper
]{scrbook}


\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[inner=2cm, outer=1.3cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx, mathtools,
enumitem,
minitoc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{probsoln}
\renewcommand{\solutionname}{Đáp số}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}
\renewcommand{\newproblem}[3]{
    \begin{defproblem}{#1}
        \begin{onlyproblem} #2 \end{onlyproblem}
        \begin{onlysolution} #3 \end{onlysolution}
    \end{defproblem}}


\everymath{\displaystyle}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{\theenumi.}}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\thechapter.\arabic{enumi}}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

%\showanswers

\chapter{Điện tích - Điện trường}

\section{Lực tương tác tĩnh điện}
\subsection{Tương tác giữa hai điện tích điểm đứng yên}
\loadallproblems[c1cd1d1]{Chuong_1_chude_1_dang_1}
\begin{enumerate}
\foreachproblem[c1cd1d1]{\item\label{prob:\thisproblemlabel}\thisproblem}
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Độ lớn của điện tích}
\loadallproblems[c1cd1d2]{Chuong_1_chude_1_dang_2}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\foreachproblem[c1cd1d2]{\item\label{prob:\thisproblemlabel}\thisproblem}
\end{enumerate}

\section{Điện trường}
\subsection{Điện trường do một điện tích điểm gây ra}
\loadallproblems[c1cd2d1]{Chuong_1_chude_2_dang_1}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\foreachproblem[c1cd2d1]{\item\label{prob:\thisproblemlabel}\thisproblem}
\end{enumerate}

\section{Đáp số}
\showanswers
\restartlist{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}
    \foreachdataset{\thisdataset}{%
    \foreachproblem[\thisdataset]{\item[\ref{prob:\thisproblemlabel}]\thisproblem}}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The answers part goes wrong! The first enumerate number should be 1.1. Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

[image: problem]

Chuong_1_chude_1_dang_1.tex

```
\newproblem{1}{
Hai điện tích $ q_1=\SI{2e-8}{C} $ và $ q_2=\SI{-e-8}{C} $ đặt cách nhau 20 cm trong không khí. Xác định độ lớn và vẽ hình lực tương tác giữa chúng?}{\SI{4.5e-5}{N}}


    \newproblem{2}{
        Hai điện tích $ q_1=\SI{2e-6}{C} $ và $ q_2=\SI{-2e-6}{C} $ đặt tại hai điểm $ A $ và $ B $ trong không khí. Lực tương tác giữa chúng là \SI{0.4}{N}. Xác định khoảng cách $ AB $, vẽ hình lực tương tác đó.}{30 cm}
```

Chuong_1_chude_1_dang_2.tex

```
\newproblem{1}{
Hai điện tích điểm bằng nhau, đặt trong chân không, cách nhau \SI{10}{cm}. Lực đẩy giữa chúng là \SI{9e-5}{N}.
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Xác định dấu và độ lớn hai điện tích đó.
    \item Để lực tương các giữa hai điện tích đó tăng 3 lần thì phải tăng hay giảm khoảng cách giữa hai điện tích đó bao nhiêu lần? Vì sao? Xác định khoảng cách giữa hai điện tích lúc đó.
\end{enumerate}}{$ q_1=q_2=\SI{e-8}{C} $ hoặc $ q_1=q_2=\SI{-e-8}{C} $; Giảm $ \sqrt{3} $ lần, $ r' \approx \SI{5.77}{cm} $ }

    \newproblem{2}{Hai điện tích có độ lớn bằng nhau, đặt cách nhau \SI{25}{cm} trong điện môi có hằng số điện môi bằng 2 thì lực tương tác giữa chúng là \SI{6.48e-3}{N}.
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Xác định độ lớn các điện tích.
    \item Nếu đưa hai điện tích đó ra không khí và vẫn giữ khoảng cách đó thì lực tương tác giữa chúng thay đổi như thế nào? Vì sao?
    \item Để lực tương tác của hai điện tích đó trong không khí vẫn là \SI{6.48e-3}{N} thì phải đặt chúng cách nhau bao nhiêu?
\end{enumerate}}{$ |q_1|=|q_2|=\SI{3e-7}{C} $; tăng 2 lần; $ r_{kk}=r_\text{đm}.\sqrt{\varepsilon} \approx \SI{35.36}{cm} $}
```

Chuong_1_chude_2_dang_1.tex

```
    \newproblem{1}{Một điện tích điểm $ q=\SI{e-6}{C} $ đặt trong không khí
\begin{enumerate}
\item Xác định cường độ điện trường tại điểm cách điện tích \SI{30}{cm}, vẽ vectơ cường độ điện trường tại điểm này.
\item Đặt điện tích trong chất lỏng có hằng số điện môi $ \varepsilon=16 $. Điểm có cường độ điện trường như câu a cách điện tích bao nhiêu.
\end{enumerate}}{}

\newproblem{2}{Cho hai điểm $ A $ và $ B $ cùng nằm trên một đường sức của điện trường do một điện tích điểm $ q > 0 $ gây ra. Biết độ lớn của cường độ điện trường tại $ A $ là \SI{36}{V/m}, tại $ B $ là \SI{9}{V/m}.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Xác định cường độ điện trường tại trung điểm $ M $ của $ AB $.
        \item Nếu đặt tại $ M $ một điện tích điểm $ q_0=\SI{-e-2}{C} $ thì độ lớn lực điện tác dụng lên $ q_0 $ là bao nhiêu? Xác định phương chiều của lực.
    \end{enumerate}}{$ E_M=\SI{16}{V/m} $; $ F_0=\SI{0,16}{N} $}
```

Comment: please try to make it minimal and complet (Chuong_1_chude_1_dang_1 's contents) for example

Comment: You edited it but it's still not compilable

Comment: Thank you. I've edited it and added two nesscessary files.

Comment: `\thisproblemlabel` is always 1 or 2, so you get multiply defined labels and at the end `\ref{prob:1}` and `\ref{prob:2}` refer the the last pair, which explains getting 5 and 6 as numbers.

Comment: @egreg can you please tell me how can solve this problem. In three .tex file I use only two problems to make it shorter. In the real file, there are more then 5 problems.